# Using recursion to indentify valid regexes

Tags: python, regex, recursion

I've been developing a program that has a function that takes a string like so: `((1.(0.2)2).0)` and returns `True` if it is a regex. Here's mmy code so far:

```
def is_regex(s):
    #Takes a string 's' and produces True if it is a valid regular expression
    #But False otherwise
    ex = '( + 3* + | + 6* + )'
    leaves = ['1', '2', '0', '1*', '2*', '0*']
    internal_nodes = ['|', '.']
    stripped_string = s.strip('()')

    if len(s.strip('()')) == 1:
        if '0' in s.strip('()') or '1' in s.strip('()') or '2' in s.strip('()')  or 'e' in s.strip('()'):
        return True
    elif len(s.strip('()')) == 0:
        return True
    elif stripped_string in leaves[3:6]:
        return True 
    elif len(stripped_string) == 3:
        if stripped_string[0] in leaves and stripped_string[2] in leaves:
            if stripped_string[1] in internal_nodes:
                return True 
    elif '.' in s and len(stripped_string) > 3:
        dot_position = s.rfind('.')
        if s.rfind('.') > s.rfind(')', 0, len(s)-1): #if '.' is only surrounded by one set of () then it is the root of the tree
            is_regex(s[dot_position +1])
```

The idea here is I want to find the root of the tree, and check if it's two children are valid regexes, if they are I move on a recurse until I'm at the leaf, if it passes all the tests until it hits the leaf then the entire regex is `True`.

For the last line I have there `is_regex(s[dot_position +1])` I'm not getting anything returned, even though I know `s[dot_position +1]` returns `0` so there should be no problem. In this line I'm checking the right child of `.` which is `0`.

Edit: Another question: I need to test whether or not the left child is true as well. How would I do this? Wouldn't I need to pass both to `is_regex`? Or should I check if both right and left are true then proceed? This is confusing

Comment: Okay so I just added a `return` statement to the last line, why does that make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the most common recursion bug in existence. If you don't `return` the result of the recursive call, Python *does not* return it for you - it keeps running the function as normal. Since there's nothing else after it, it falls off the end without returning - and Python's rules mean that it will then implicitly `return None`. The result of `is_regex(s[dot_position + 1])` is *ignored*, unless you explicitly return it (or otherwise use it somehow).

---

You have a similar bug in two of the other paths through this function:

```
if len(s.strip('()')) == 1:
    if '0' in s.strip('()') or '1' in s.strip('()') or '2' in s.strip('()')  or 'e' in s.strip('()'):
    return True

elif len(stripped_string) == 3:
    if stripped_string[0] in leaves and stripped_string[2] in leaves:
        if stripped_string[1] in internal_nodes:
            return True
```

in both of these cases, if the outer if triggers but the inner ifs fail, you will end up returning None. This isn't as serious an issue, because `None` will still test false when calling code does `if is_regex(not_a_regex)` - but for the sake of consistency and explicitly handling these cases (instead of essentially forgetting them and having it *happen* to work), you probably want to return `False`. The easiest way to do that is to just return the boolean expressions instead of testing them:

```
if len(s.strip('()')) == 1:
    return '0' in s.strip('()') or '1' in s.strip('()') or '2' in s.strip('()')  or 'e' in s.strip('()')

elif len(stripped_string) == 3:
    return stripped_string[0] in leaves and stripped_string[2] in leaves and stripped_string[1] in internal_nodes
```

---

For testing the left child as well, you would indeed have to recurse into both - *separately*, mind (passing them into the same recursive call might be doable, but is unlikely to work). I would do it this way:

```
dot_position = s.rfind('.')
if s.rfind('.') > s.rfind(')', 0, len(s)-1): #if '.' is only surrounded by one set of () then it is the root of the tree
    left_child =  s[dot_position - 1]
    right child = s[dot_position + 1]
    return is_regex(left_child) and is_regex(right_child)
```

This is a very common pattern in any algorithm involving tree structures: test something about the value in the current node, and then test all of its subtrees by recursively calling the same routine on each child in turn; return a result that is dependent on the results of all the recursive calls. Wikipedia calls this a ['depth-first pre-order walk'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order).

Comment: I see, thanks for that insight. Is there any way you could help me with my second question there? After I check the right and left children how would I go about recursing in to each of those children if they're *both* trees? It'd be like recursing twice simultaneously

Comment: Wow thanks, the answer seems so simple. I'm glad this dilemma is actually documented. I knew I needed a way to determine if both children were valid, thanks again, cheers!